# how to validate expansion panel title highlight, when expansion panel having input field and while having empty value In Angular

Tags: javascript, angular6, angular7

Am trying to create Expansion Panel in Angular 7, I have a small issue. In expansion panel title section font colour should change when the expansion panel input field having data, it must changed to green , if input field is empty panel title should be in red colour. i tried for that but i didn't get , can u please help me out.

Thanks & Regards

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup2">
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="step === 0"(opened)="setStep(0)"hideToggle>
 <mat-expansion-panel-header>
   <i class="material-icons">arrow_right_alt</i>Call Volumes
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>      
    <mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
        <mat-form-field style="width: 300px; padding: 10px;" class="example-full-width">
          <input matInput placeholder="Calls / Volumes / Transaction per month" formControlName="secondCtrl" required>
        </mat-form-field>  
        <mat-form-field style="width: 350px; padding: 10px;">
          <input matInput placeholder="AHT Per call / volume / transaction in Seconds" formControlName="eighthCtrl" required>
        </mat-form-field>
    </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>  
    <mat-action-row>
    <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="nextStep()">Next</button>
    </mat-action-row>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</form>
```

Here is the app.component.ts code

```
formGroup2: FormGroup;

constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder ) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup2 = this._formBuilder.group({
    eighthCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
});
```